# Issue while converting date column from csv to date as per R

Tags: r, data-conversion

Following is the error I am getting when trying to convert the date column read from csv

```
data<-read.csv("data.csv",stringsasfactors=FALSE) #data<-read.table("data.csv",sep=",",header=TRUE)

as.Date(data$Date,"%Y-%d-%m")
```

**Error:**

```
error in as.date.default(x ...) do not know how to convert 'x' to class date
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, could you provide a sample of your data? Otherwise it is difficult to help you in solving the problem

Comment: the date column from the csv looks like this  30-06-2003,30-09-2003,31-12-2003 I have edited the quetion

Comment: You can use `data$Date <- lubridate::dmy(data$Date)`

Answer (score 0):

If your dates look like `30-06-2003`, then you need to adjust the format in which you want to read them accordingly. With this, I mean that the right format is `"%d-%m-%Y"`, i.e. *day - month - 4 digit year*, and not `"%Y-%d-%m"`.

Try this line

```
as.Date(data$Date, format = "%d-%m-%Y")
```

Comment: Even after re-assigning the new variable to the original one? I mean doing `data$Date <- as.Date(data$Date, format = "%d-%m-%Y")`   - sorry for the stupid question, just wanna check out why it behaves like that for you